# Does sympy.rem() run in polynomial time?

Tags: python, time-complexity, modulo

I am currently using the code

```
sym.rem((x + a)**n -(x**n + a), x**r - 1)
```

to check whether the polynomial (x+a)^n is congruent to (x^n + a) modulo (x^r - 1). However, I have noticed that as the size of n increases, the time taken for this line to run increases very dramatically.

Does sympy.rem() run in polynomial time?